# How to interpret a dump of binary file?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, objdump

Consider the following part of output from dump of a binary file (amd64):

```
$ objdump -D /lib/modules/4.16.0-1-amd64/kernel/drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.ko
...
25f0:       e8 00 00 00 00          callq  25f5 <acm_port_dtr_rts+0x5>
25f5:       53                      push   %rbx
25f6:       48 89 fb                mov    %rdi,%rbx
25f9:       48 83 ef 20             sub    $0x20,%rdi
25fd:       85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
25ff:       74 3c                   je     263d <acm_port_dtr_rts+0x4d>
2601:       b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax
2606:       b9 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%ecx
260b:       f6 83 60 08 00 00 40    testb  $0x40,0x860(%rbx)
2612:       89 83 94 07 00 00       mov    %eax,0x794(%rbx)
2618:       75 18                   jne    2632 <acm_port_dtr_rts+0x42>
261a:       48 8d 73 e8             lea    -0x18(%rbx),%rsi
261e:       45 31 c9                xor    %r9d,%r9d
2621:       45 31 c0                xor    %r8d,%r8d
2624:       ba 22 00 00 00          mov    $0x22,%edx
2629:       e8 32 eb ff ff          callq  1160 <acm_ctrl_msg.isra.10>
262e:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
2630:       74 09                   je     263b <acm_port_dtr_rts+0x4b>
2632:       f6 83 1c 08 00 00 02    testb  $0x2,0x81c(%rbx)
2639:       75 08                   jne    2643 <acm_port_dtr_rts+0x53>
263b:       5b                      pop    %rbx
263c:       c3                      retq
263d:       89 f1                   mov    %esi,%ecx
263f:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
2641:       eb c8                   jmp    260b <acm_port_dtr_rts+0x1b>
2643:       48 8b 7b e8             mov    -0x18(%rbx),%rdi
2647:       48 c7 c6 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rsi
264e:       5b                      pop    %rbx
264f:       48 83 c7 30             add    $0x30,%rdi
2653:       e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   2658 <acm_port_dtr_rts+0x68>
2658:       0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
265f:       00
...
```

The following part from [cdc-acm.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a638af00b27266c09ab7ac69141e6f4ac6c00eff/drivers/usb/class/cdc-acm.c) corresponds to above dump:

```
static void acm_port_dtr_rts(struct tty_port *port, int raise)
{
  struct acm *acm = container_of(port, struct acm, port);
  int val;
  int res;

  if (raise)
        val = ACM_CTRL_DTR | ACM_CTRL_RTS;
  else
        val = 0;

  acm->ctrlout = val;

  res = acm_set_control(acm, val);
  if (res && (acm->ctrl_caps & USB_CDC_CAP_LINE))
        dev_err(&acm->control->dev, "failed to set dtr/rts\n");
}
```

Also, the following constants are used here:

```
#define ACM_CTRL_DTR            0x01
#define ACM_CTRL_RTS            0x02
```

How to find out which line in the dump corresponds to the following line from source code?

```
val = ACM_CTRL_DTR | ACM_CTRL_RTS;
```

**EDIT**

The following procedure was used to change the binary:

```
hexdump -v -e "1/1 \" %02x\n\"" cdc-acm.ko.orig >text_file
<edit text_file>
xxd -r -p text_file cdc-acm.ko
```

Comment: In csc-acm.h `ACM_CTRL_DTR` is 0x01 and `ACM_CTRL_RTS` is  0x02 . 0x01 | 0x02 = 0x03. The compiler computed this as a compile time optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compiled with debug info, then `objdump -d -S` to interleave source lines with asm.  `gdb` can use external debug symbols (like from `linux-image-4.16.0-1-amd64-dbg`) but I don't think that's useful for disassembling kernel modules.

I'm not sure how to tell `objdump` to look for / use them.  See https://www.technovelty.org/code/separate-debug-info.html for some more info about separate debug info, but it doesn't say anything about `objdump -S` using them, only gdb.

---

Otherwise, `ACM_CTRL_DTR | ACM_CTRL_RTS` is `0x3`, and there's a test/je that skips over a couple `mov $3, %eax` / `mov $3, %ecx` instructions when something `%esi` is zero, so that's `if(raise)` branch.  The 2nd integer function arg is passed in RSI/ESI in the x86-64 System V calling convention, so that's `raise` unless it's been clobbered by an earlier `call` or some other thing you hid with `...`.

The two `mov` instructions are probably explained by assigning `val` to something else, but I haven't tried to fully follow the logic.

Comment: `raise` comes from function argument - I have added it to OP. Also, there is the following debug package in Debian `linux-image-4.16.0-1-amd64-dbg`.  Is it possible to use it, and if yes - how? The final goal is to change that value to `0` without recompiling the whole kernel.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko: I'm not sure if it's possible to use external debug symbols with `objdump -d -S`.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko looks to me like changing `25fd: 85 f6   test %esi,%esi` to `31 f6  xorl %esi,%esi` will achieve what you want, but modifying machine code after compilation from C source is always fragile, because next time after some subtle source change (even in different part of that source file, or some header which is included) the compiler may produce considerably different machine code, so maybe you reconsider how to adjust it in the source before build (or how to build quickly). Or at least detect wider area of opcodes around, so you will patch it only when the code is "like this".

Comment: @IgorLiferenko that proposed patch is like changing `if (raise)` to `if (raise=0)` (that's not a typo, it's assignment inside the `if` expression).

Comment: @Ped7g I tried to simply change `03` to `00` in two places, and it worked perfectly. See **EDIT** in OP. I did not try your variant yet. Do you think my solution is good, or yours would be preferable? P.S. I use local machine for testing - I can recompile kernel in Debian without problems - the main usage of this hack is necessary on openwrt devices (which I update very rarely) which I have quite a few, and I use image builder to generate firmware for them (compile from source would be too much hassle). So, binary patch is a good solution.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko changing both `3` to `0` seems also valid approach. `raise` doesn't seem to be used in following code, so the both variants are identical, my would be somewhat different if `raise` would be used later again, yours modifies only `val`.